# How to put a sum in a String and print it

Tags: java, mysql

I'm currently working on a receipt of an Java application and I can't seem to get the sum on the screen. When is use the following query I get the sum in PHPMyAdmin but can't seem to find it in Java. I just can't print it because Java tells me all the column names I try are wrong. Does anyone know how to fix this?

If you want more code than this I can provide that but I'm kinda sure there is something faulty in the query and Java can't read it out. Help will be appreciated.

```
String sql = "SELECT sum((`barorder_drink`.`quantity` * `drink`.`price`)) + sum((`kitchenorder_dish`.`quantity` * `dish`.`price`))"
        + "FROM `barorder`, `barorder_drink`, `drink`, `kitchenorder`, `kitchenorder_dish`, `dish`, `restaurantorder`"
        + "WHERE `barorder`.`restaurantOrderId` = `restaurantorder`.`id`"
        + "AND `kitchenorder`.`restaurantOrderId` = `restaurantorder`.`id`"
        + "AND `barorder_drink`.`barorderId` = `barorder`.`id`"
        + "AND `barorder_drink`.`drinkId` = `drink`.`id`"
        + "AND `kitchenorder_dish`.`kitchenOrderId` = `kitchenorder`.`id`"
        + "AND `kitchenorder_dish`.`dishId` = `dish`.`id`"
        + "AND `restaurantorder`.`id` = '" + ID + "' ;";
```

Comment: You need to start smaller and then clarify your question. Can you get any query to work? How about a slightly more complicated query? What does the code executing the query actually look like, what APIs and libraries are you using?

Comment: Why so many apostrophes? Also, [sanitize your SQL input!](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your sum as a val and get this value like this

```
String sql = "SELECT sum(myattributes) AS val";
```

and when you want to get the result

```
int som = getInt("val");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you do ))"
+ "FROM ...

The result is: ))FROM
and it sould be )) FROM